# Sumar días de rangos en un mes en oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo la siguiente tabla con
 cabecera

> (Código - Fecha_Ini - Fecha_Fin - Días)

y los valores son

> (COD01 - 01/05/2018 - 06/05/2018 - 6)
>    (COD02 - 10/05/2018 - 14/05/2018 - 5)
>    (COD03 - 20/05/2018 - 22/05/2018 - 3)
>    (COD04 - 25/05/2018 - 26/05/2018 - 2)

Deseo obtener dos resultados la suma del primer rango y la suma de los posteriores rangos al primero. En el ejemplo el resultado seria: PrimerRango = 6 días, y el resto de rangos = 10 días.

Comment: Bienevenido Juanka a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora. Saludos.

Comment: Cual seria el primer rango? es siempre el mismo? que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: El primer rango siempre va iniciar el primer día del mes en este caso 01/05/2018 hasta 06/05/2018.

Comment: select  codigo, fecha_ini, fecha_fin, sum(dias) 
   from tabla_datos
   where to_date(fecha_ini, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between '01/05/2018' and '31/05/2018' 
   group by codigo, fecha_ini, fecha_fin

Answer (score 1):

Logre obtener el resultado con dos consultas. Las comparto si alguien le sirve.

*Para sumar el primer rango

```
SELECT SUM(NVL(DIAS,0))
FROM( select row_number() over (order by codigo desc) as rank, codigo, 
      fecha_ini, fecha_fin, sum(dias) DIAS
      from NombreTabla
      where to_date(fecha_ini, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between fIniMes and fFinMes
      group by codigo, fecha_ini, fecha_fin
      order by FECHA_INI
     ) A 
WHERE A.RANK = 1;
```

*Para sumar los demás rangos a excepción del primer rango

```
SELECT SUM(NVL(DIAS,0))
FROM( select row_number() over (order by codigo desc) as rank, codigo, 
      fecha_ini, fecha_fin, sum(dias) DIAS
      from NombreTabla
      where to_date(fecha_ini, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between fIniMes and fFinMes
      group by codigo, fecha_ini, fecha_fin
      order by FECHA_INI
     ) A 
WHERE A.RANK > 1;
```